# jQuery not returning edited HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

JS:

```
$( '.copydump' ).click(function(){
    var cp = $('.copy');

    $('.bin').html( $(cp).html() );
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="copy">
    <textarea class="textarea">cows</textarea>
</div>
<input type="button" class="copydump" value='go'/>
<div class="bin"></div>
```

I need to take a complete copy of some dynamic content but with the new values of the form elements.

The above js will only move the form as it loaded up, ie the old form values. In [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yH4DZ/), if you alter the content from 'cows' then press 'go' you will see what i mean.

I know I can query the value of the textarea before moving the content, but does anyone know an automated way within jQuery to do this?

Comment: I think you'll find the innerHTML of the element isn't updating. You probably want to update the text area's HTML to contain it's value after HTML encoding.

Comment: Thanks @Adam spot on. I cannot believe i have not ever come across this issue before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner text of a text area does not get updated when you type in it. You can write a function that will update it if that's what you want it to do.

Then when you copy the html it will get the updated html of the textarea.

```
// function that will updated the text area's innerHTML every time the value of the text changes.
$('.textarea').change(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).val());
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yH4DZ/3/)

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the copied text box to be something else you will want to us `.val()`

```
$('.bin').html( $(cp).html() ).find('textarea').val(cp.find('textarea').val());
```

Comment: Yes, thanks good spot. But this did not make any difference:  http://jsfiddle.net/yH4DZ/1/

Comment: @John yeah, that was my mistake. try it now

Comment: Cheers @Adjit for the help